KVM bridge not assign IP to vm which is already a bridge member
I have a problem of configuring a network bridge for VM which is not assigning IP address after use of systemback and dd import data to the new VM.
Here is my systemd-networkd configuration information:
Running Ubuntu 24.04 LVM2 server, KVM virtual-manager. bridge network configured.
taimon@lvmserver:/etc/libvirt/qemu$ ip a s

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:64:c4:cf:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:d4:22:c3:9e:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.18/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global bridge0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e8d4:22ff:fec3:9e35/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

23: vnet18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:89:91:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe89:913a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

29: vnet24: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:bb:70:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:febb:7076/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The networkctl configured interface and bridge setup. There has 2 VMs running, one have IP and other doesn't have IP after restore from systemback iso.
taimon@lvmserver:/etc/libvirt/qemu$ networkctl

IDX LINK    TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo      loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp6s0  ether    enslaved    configured
  4 bridge0 bridge   routable    configured
 23 vnet18  ether    enslaved    unmanaged
 29 vnet24  ether    enslaved    unmanaged

taimon@lvmserver:/etc/libvirt/qemu$ brctl show

bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces

bridge0     8000.ead422c39e35   yes     enp6s0
                                   vnet18
                                   vnet24

The vnet18 created by using ubuntu iso, IP address assigned
New vm with IP assigned,can access internet
The vnet24 vm created by using systemback.iso restore from my old LVM.
vnet24:create by using live systemback restore, the subnet interface enp1s0 state is DOWN, don't get any IP
 <interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:db:1d:47"/>
  <source bridge="bridge0"/>
  <target dev="vnet26"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

Some one said need to regenerate UUID after dd copy data, however, the LVM could not mount because of not ext.4 format.
========================================================
The vnet25 nic.xml file from the one has ip assigned
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:89:91:3a"/>
  <source bridge="bridge0"/>
  <target dev="vnet25"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

==============================================================
If the vnet29(segamlf) boot from nic, it can see ip address but not bootable

vnet29
=================================================================
This VM name vnet29 "segamlf".xml file below:
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>segamlf</name>
  <uuid>d84c9879-b567-46d4-a010-acbf79e487ac</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://libosinfo.org/linux/2022"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-8.2">hvm</type>
    <bootmenu enable="yes"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="block" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native" discard="unmap"/>
      <source dev="/dev/sega_vg/sega_mlf"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="7" port="0x16"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="8" port="0x17"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="9" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="9" port="0x18"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="10" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="10" port="0x19"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="11" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="11" port="0x1a"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="12" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="12" port="0x1b"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="13" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="13" port="0x1c"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="14" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="14" port="0x1d"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="15" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="15" port="0x1e"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="16" model="pcie-to-pci-bridge">
      <model name="pcie-pci-bridge"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <mac address="52:54:00:1a:89:5f"/>
      <source bridge="bridge0"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="unix">
      <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich9">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="spice"/>
    <video>
      <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <watchdog model="itco" action="reset"/>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model="virtio">
      <backend model="random">/dev/urandom</backend>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
</domain>


This is all information is totally useless. The problem is with the network configuration within the VM, show us that details instead. Very likely after the "migration" you did to the VM "the hard way", the vNIC was assigned to another virtual PCI slot than it "occupied" before, so therefore that stupid systemd's "predictable interface naming" (which in fact just relies on slot numbers) had given the vNIC another name within the VM, so the present configuration that mention the old vNIC name doesn't apply to it anymore.

Also, the screenshots has to be textual copy-paste as everything else. These are textual information inherently. It's easy to acquire that information as text even from networkless VM, so "no network" is not an excuse. We expect the information about the VM network configuration in textual form, should you present one here.

Using bootup menu 1)nic 2) virtlO disk. The nic get an ip 192.168.1.227 but it is not bootable, than follow by virtlO bootup. The VM fail to connect internet and no ip assigned as the result. The xml file update in the question.

@NikitaKipriyanov, I can build a new VM by importing the old LVM image and booting it up. However, no ip was assigned and no internet connection. Would you give me some solutions?
